# Is python's heapq.heapify() faster on a list that is close to a heap?

Tags: python, heap, heapq

Like the title says, I would like to know if python's heapq.heapify() will work faster on a list that is close to a heap or does it do the entire operation element by element on every list?

I'm debating on how often to use heapify().

Comment: You can see the source [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/39a54ba63850e081a4a5551a773df5b4d5b1d3cd/Lib/heapq.py#L170). It's O(n) as the docs say, but [`_siftup`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/39a54ba63850e081a4a5551a773df5b4d5b1d3cd/Lib/heapq.py#L260) "bubbles", so it should be faster the less bubbling it needs to do.

Comment: You should only need to call `heapify` once: after that only use the `heappush` and `heappop` methods (and the like) so that your heap will *stay* a heap. If you need to "debate on how often to use heapify" you're probably doing it wrong.

Comment: @trincot I don't think that's correct advice. For example, if you have a heap of size *n* and you have to add *n* more elements to the heap, it is asymptotically more efficient to push them all to the list and call heapify once, than it is to call heappush *n* times. Any use-case where you have to do batch insertions will have a trade-off like this, and it will take some analysis or experimentation to figure out when a batch insertion is better to do with one heapify vs. some number of heappushes.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious answer is yes. If you supply a sorted array to `heapify` it won't have to perform any swaps at all. If you supply a reverse-sorted array it will have to perform the maximum number of swaps.

That said, there is no benefit to pre-sorting the array before passing it to `heapify` because the total time (i.e. analyzing and arranging the array, plus `heapify` time) will exceed the maximum time required for `heapify` to do its work on even the worst-case arrangement.

That said, you shouldn't have to call `heapify` more than once. That is, you call `heapify` to construct the heap. Then you call the `heappush` and `heappop` methods to add and remove items.

I suppose, if you have to add a large number of items to an existing heap, you could append them to an existing heap and then call `heapify` to re-build the heap. Hard to say the exact circumstances under which that would be useful. I'd certainly give any such code a big ol' WTF if I were to see it in a code review.

Comment: Using heapify for batch insertions will have an asymptotic advantage when the batch size is on the order of `n / log n`. That could be like inserting 50,000 elements into a priority queue of size 1,000,000 - it's not that implausible for some specific applications.

Comment: @kaya3 Not implausible, but definitely a special case. And something I'd be very careful about advocating.